# "DirectConsumerNotAvailableException" in apache camel on shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, shutdown

I have 4 routes in my application. I have used below code to close route in same order they are started:

```
getContext().getShutdownStrategy().setShutdownRoutesInReverseOrder(false);
```

From the logs I can see that routes are stopping in same order. but the problem is I can see in logs multiple "DirectConsumerNotAvailableException" because first route is sending exchanges to second route but second route is not available by that time. Why is it happening?

Comment: Can't you just use the default shutdown sequence it ought to work in 99+% use-cases. If not set the startupOrder options on the routes, or re-order them in your RouteBuilder classes.

Comment: startupOrder is set on all the routes.